# How to run Chart Boost demo on Xcode in unity3d?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, chartboost

I have run chart boost demo which have been provided at chart boost site.
It shows error like below,

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/jeganselvaraj/Unity3D/SlotMachine_IOS/Libraries/libChartboost.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/jeganselvaraj/Unity3D/SlotMachine_IOS/Libraries/libChartboost.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CBAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChartBoostBinding.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Chartboost", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ChartBoostBinding.o
      objc-class-ref in ChartBoostManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What can I do for this issue?

Comment: Are you running Unity3D plugin? If yes - do you use real device?

Comment: `architecture i386` means it's looking for a [32 bit (x86)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_architecture) CPU. Phones usually use a completely different CPU architecture called [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture), so by the looks of it, the library you're using won't work on such phones.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is no *libChartboost.a* in your Xcode project's *Libraries* folder.

You need to ensure that file *libChartboost.a* is in directory *Assets/Plugins/iOS*. All files from *Assets/Plugins/iOS* are copied to the Xcode project automatically during Unity's build process. Note that subdirectories within *Assets/Plugins/iOS* are not considered.